# Send an email with attachment with C# and XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, email

I am building a windows 8 desktop app. I have an email form with a textbox and a button.
XAML below.

```
<TextBox x:Name="email_txt"></TextBox>
<Button x:Name="email_btn" Content="Emial Me"  Click="email_btn_Click"/>
```

How do I send a an email with an attachment to the email address entered in `email_txt` when `email_btn` is clicked.

I used the following in the c# code behind the XAML page

```
 private async void email_btn_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var mailto = new Uri("mailto:?to=tr@gmail.com&subject=Hello&body=Test Tocuh Email");
            await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);*/

        }
```

This code just opens MS Outlook with the message type.

How do I send an email with an attachment when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Note that this class by default will take smtp configurations from you application config file.

```
        var mailMessage = new MailMessage("test@example.com", email_txt.Text, "Hello", "Test");
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        byte[] attachmentData; //get attachment data as byte array.
        var attachmentStream = new MemoryStream(attachmentData);
        var attachment = new Attachment(attachmentStream, "Test");

        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Comment: Can I still use SMTP in windows 8 apps? Doesn't seem to recognize it? What assembly reference do I use for `MailMessage`

Comment: Add "using System.Net;" to your source file.

Comment: still doesn't recognize `Message`

Comment: Ok, sorry for that. MailMessage class is in "System.Net.Mail" namespace so you have to add "using System.Net.Mail;" as well.

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't recognize `System.Net.Mail`, I don't think this is applicable to Windows 8 apps

Comment: That's odd, it says that it supports Windows 8 and Windows 8.1. Probably i'm confusing app stores again :S. Sorry for that. Have you tried to add reference to System.dll?

Comment: I don't think it is, I checked the approved list, and did  some research, and it seems that the only way is with a Share Contract

Answer (score 0):

The WinRT (Win App) platform doesn't have any built-in SMTP client. Instead you can use the share charm in order to send emails.

See [Sharing content source app sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84).

- [How to share files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh871371)
- [How to share text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh871372)
- [How to share HTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh973055)

I would include some code, but I'm not on my Windows 8 machine.

Comment: I tried the code here [link]http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84/sourcecode?fileId=43981&pathId=1926429020 but it only allows me to select a file from my machine. How do I send a predefined file to an email address?